# With pytorch DataLoader how to take in two ndarray (data & label)?

Tags: pytorch

I have a training data features in ndarray of shape (100, 400, 3) as it's 100 images of 20x20 with RGB channel and label in shape (100, ). Do I need to combine them into one dataset or how can I pass it to Pytorch dataLoader in order to iterate over image and label later?

What I've tried so far

```
#turn ndarray of features and labels into tensors
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToPILImage(),
                                transforms.ToTensor()])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Shai mentioned, `DataLoader` requires the input to be the `Dataset` class or its subclass. One of the simplest subclasses is `TensorDataset` and you can convert it from ndarray.

```py
import torch
import numpy as np
import torch.utils as utils

train_x = torch.Tensor(np.random.randn(100,400,3))
train_y = torch.Tensor(np.random.randint(0,2,100))

dataset = utils.data.TensorDataset(train_x, train_y)
dataloader = utils.data.DataLoader(dataset)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [convert](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.from_numpy) your data/label ndarrays to `torch.tensor` and use [`torch.utils.data.TensorDataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.1.0/data.html#torch.utils.data.TensorDataset) to create a dataset that iterates over your examples.
Once you have a dataset, you can wrap a [`DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.1.0/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) around it to be used for training.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've included what I tried in the updated question. My main current issue is dataLoader seems to work on a dataset with both features and labels. But if I combine the features tensor and labels tensor into dataset with
torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(transform(train_x),transform(train_y))
I get error "pic should be 2/3 dimensional. Got 1 dimensions", which is mainly because the label is a 1 dimension one. how can I properly combine label with features into one dataset? thanks!